# ssh : The term 'ssh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have tried to connect to a server using ssh but  I got the following error ssh :

```
The term 'ssh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I have followed the tutorial from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#:~:text=Install%20OpenSSH%20using%20PowerShell.%20To%20install%20OpenSSH%20using,the%20following%20output%20if%20neither%20are%20already%20installed%3A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#:%7E:text=Install%20OpenSSH%20using%20PowerShell.%20To%20install%20OpenSSH%20using,the%20following%20output%20if%20neither%20are%20already%20installed%3A)

and managed to install OpenSSH.client and server but I get the same error when trying to run ssh.

[image]

I am running on Windows 10 Pro.
I have tried uninstalling OpenSSH and reinstalling it back, restarting the computer but nothing changed.

**EDIT :**
In a strange way, ssh started working the very next day. I guess the solution was to restart the computer after uninstalling and reinstalling ssh back.

Comment: This is not "strange": your original screenshot shows you tried to use ssh in the same shell session in which you installed OpenSSH. My answwer is about opening a new session.

Comment: I confirm. Literally it doesnt work when restarting the SSH, but it works after restarting the computer

Answer (score 3):

In my case, OpenSSH was installed properly and the folder structure was also ok.
However, the ssh syntax was not accepted. So, the solution was just to execute the ssh.exe as:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\openssh> .\ssh
```

Answer (score 2):

Try first the same command in a *new* Powershell Windows, one which will inherit from the system changes you just did by installing [OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview)

Make sure you do see a `C:\Windows\System32\openssh\ssh.exe`.

As mentioned in "[OpenSSH Server Configuration for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration)"

> First confirm that the OpenSSH installation folder is on the system path.
>
> For Windows, the default installation folder is `SystemDrive:WindowsDirectory\System32\openssh`.

Comment: Somehow, the very next day it started working without doing anything to it. Probably it was expecting another computer restart. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But when I looked through the path variables on my other laptop, where I have been using **ssh** as well, I saw that the file **OpenSSH** was not added there. This was the solution for me.

Add **%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH** to the path variable and start a new powershell. You should now be able to use ssh without getting the error.